# print the number in this form using javascript display output on console.log

Tags: javascript

I want to print numbers in  this format.

```
    1
   121
  12321
 1234321
123454321
```

I wrote a function that prints some numbers but it is not the same as the output. I think the bug is maybe inside one of the for loops.
Here's my code:

```js
    var numRows = 5,
        triangle, 
        start, 
        stop;

    function pascalRecursive(n, a) {
      if (n < 2) return a; 

      var prevRow = a[a.length-1];
      var curRow = [1];

      for (var i = 1; i < prevRow.length; i++) {
        curRow[i] = prevRow[i] + prevRow[i];
      }
      curRow.push(1);
      a.push(curRow);

      return pascalRecursive(n-1, a); 
    }

    var triangle = pascalRecursive(numRows, [[1]]);
    for(var i = 0; i < triangle.length; i++)
      console.log(triangle[i]+"\n");
```

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. There's no actual question yet--and no description of what actually *is* happening, or what steps you've taking to diagnose the problem (debugger, REPL experimentation, etc).

Comment: @DaveNewton exactly the edit I was making!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could you a map function to increase all the numbers of the previous line by 1
then just stick a 1 to the front and end.

```
function pascalRecursive(n, a) {
  if (n < 2) return a;

  var prevRow = a[a.length - 1];
  var prevRowIncreased = prevRow.map(x => x + 1);
  a.push([1,...prevRowIncreased,1]);

  return pascalRecursive(n - 1, a);
}
```